# HyperLinkListener not triggering - java swing

Tags: java, html, swing

I'm trying to implement a JEditorPane with hyperlinks. I'm using a HyperLinkListener but it seems to never trigger.

Code:

```
JEditorPane editorPane = new JEditorPane("text/html", programInfo);

editorPane.addHyperlinkListener(e -> {
    System.out.println("CLICK");
    if (e.getEventType().equals(HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ENTERED))
        try {
            if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
                Desktop.getDesktop().browse(e.getURL().toURI());
                }
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(contentPane, editorPane);
```

Sample HTML:

```
 <body>
 <p><b>Author:</b> James - <a href="http://www.sample.co.uk">sample</a></p>
 </body>
```

This leads to this:

[image: Imgur upload of JEditorPane]

But when I click on the links nothing happens.

**Additional Info:**

I'm testing this on Ubuntu 14.04.
I have set Look and Feel to system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: thanks to @AndrewThompson for finding the real issue.
The reason why it does not trigger events is because the editor pane will only fire events when it is not editable. So, to make your code work you should add this line after the construction of the editorPane:

```
editorPane.setEditable(false);
```

Below you can find a self contained example:

```
public class TestFrame extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JEditorPane editorPane = new JEditorPane("text/html", "test <a href=\"http://example.com\">link to example.com</a>");
        editorPane.addHyperlinkListener(new HyperlinkListener() {
            @Override
            public void hyperlinkUpdate(HyperlinkEvent e) {
                System.out.println("CLICK");
                if (e.getEventType().equals(HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ENTERED)) try {
                    if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
                        Desktop.getDesktop().browse(e.getURL().toURI());
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch (URISyntaxException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        editorPane.setEditable(false); // otherwise ignores hyperlink events!

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("EditorPane Example");
        frame.add(editorPane);
        frame.setSize(300,200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    } }
```

(sorry, I removed the lambda because I don't have a jdk8 on this PC)

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with `JFrame`/`JDialog` and everything to do with `editorPane.setEditable(false);` ..  An editor pane will only fire events when it is not editable.

Comment: I'm pleased to say that Andrew is correct. Once I made the pane not editable it worked perfectly. Could you make this an answer so I can select it please?

Comment: ouch, I missed that. Thanks Andrew!

Comment: *"Could you make this an answer so I can select it please?"*  I would prefer to see @AndreaIacono add a code comment to their answer to the effect `editorPane.setEditable(false);  // otherwise ignores hyperlink events!` ..  It is a solid answer (that included the right method call) that could just do with that one small tweak/clarification.